# Child struct lifetime is bounded by its Parent struct lifetime

Tags: rust

Currently, I have a code where I need that Child struct have a reference to field 'x' of its Parent struct. For those needs I did workaround with using Rc<>.

```
  #[derive(Clone)]
  pub struct SomeBigStruct {
    pub value: u32,
    // ... plus many vector properties
  }
  
  pub struct ParentV1 {
    pub x: SomeBigStruct,
    pub children: Vec<ChildV1>,
  }

  pub struct ChildV1 {
    pub x_ref: Rc<SomeBigStruct>,
  }

  fn new_parent_v1() -> ParentV1 {
    let x = SomeBigStruct{value: 42};
    let x_ref = Rc::new(x.clone());
    ParentV1 {
      x,
      children: vec![
        ChildV1 { x_ref: x_ref.clone() },
        ChildV1 { x_ref: x_ref.clone() },
        //... plus thousands of another children
      ],
    }
  }
```

This works, but I was wondering that simple reference with lifetime should be also feasible. Because lifetime of struct which I want to refer is known (same as Parent struct lifetime). Something like:

```
  pub struct ParentV2 {
    pub x: SomeBigStruct,
    pub children: Vec<ChildV2<'lifetime_of_parent_struct>>,
  }

  pub struct ChildV2<'a> {
    pub x_ref: &'a SomeBigStruct,
  }

  fn new_parent_v2<'a>() -> ParentV2<'a> {
    let x = SomeBigStruct{value: 42};
    ParentV2 {
      children: vec![
        ChildV2 { x_ref: &x },
        ChildV2 { x_ref: &x },
      ],
      x,
    }
  }
```

This of course cannot be compiled because I do not know how define reference only to Parent struct lifetime. Is it even possible? If not is there any better workaround than mine? Thanks.